# Import file of semi-known name to pandas and return filename

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm writing a script to import a csv using pandas, then upload it to a SQL server.  It all works when I have a test file with one name, but that won't be the case in production.  I need to figure out how to import with only a semi-known filename (the filename will always follow the same convention, but there will be differences in the filenames such as dates/times).  I should, however, note that there will only ever be one csv file in the folder it's checking.  I have tried the wildcard in the import path, but that didn't work.

After it's imported, I also then need to return the filename.

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, would this be an accurate re-statement of your question: "Given a directory name, find the name of the only CSV file in it"? If so, `glob.glob(os.path.join(dir, "*.csv"))[0]` or `pathlib.Path(dir).glob("*.csv")[0]` should do that.

Comment: That looks like it'd probably work.  I'll try that out!

Comment: Update, it did indeed work.  Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all files in a directory with extension .txt in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Look into the OS module:

```
import os
files = os.listdir("./")
csv_files = [filename for filename in files if filename.endswith(".csv")]
```

`csv_files` is a list with all the files that ends with `.csv`